# How do I make the code card not require a connection to the database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, code-map

### Question:

How do I make the code card not require a connection to the database?

---

### Description

I'm trying to figure out the project.
I built a code map.
When I click on a project on the code map, I get an error.

I use: Visual Studio-2022 Enterprise

---

### Error:

> The XML content of this document cannot be represented as a graph because it contains unexpected errors. Open the XML editor to fix these errors and try to reopen the graph.
> The detected error is described below.

> Unable to connect to the specified database.
> An exception occurred or an attempt was made to connect to the database using the following connection string:
> `Data Source=(Local)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Asynchronous Processing=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30.`
> Verify that the specified instance of SQL Server exists and the service is running.

> Call Stack:
> in Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.OpenAndConfigureConnection(SqlConnection connection)
> in Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0()
> in Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.ExecuteRepositoryAction(Action action)
> in Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.UsingMasterConnection(String connectionString, Action`1 act)
> in Microsoft.Repository.Utilities.GetDbStateAndFileNames(SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder)
> in Microsoft.Repository.Utilities.GetDatabaseState(String connectionString)
> in Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.ProgressiveReveal.PRUtilities.CanQuery(ActionContext context, IProgressionCacheSettings settings)
> in Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.ProgressiveReveal.GetRepositoryTimestampsCommand.Execute(ActionContext context, IGraphStatus statusReporter, IProgressionCacheSettings settings)
> in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.ActionManager.CallNormalActions(Action action, ActionContext actionContext, Boolean propagateCancellation)

### Pictures:

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

**Picture-4**
[image]